# Using GitHub to listen to changes made to files on remote server

Tags: github, remote-server

I know there are a lot of posts about running GitHub on a remote server, but I can't find any that I understand or can follow. Command line stuff and all this talk about SSH completely befuddle me, so I am hoping for a step-by-step answer which is literally written for a dummy and hopefully provides an easy solution (I am having my fingers and toes crossed).

My scenario:

I have built a site using Statamic as a CMS, which uses text files to manage the site's content. I also have a GitHub repository which contains most of the site's files here: 
https://github.com/katrinkerber/katrinkerber

I am using the GitHub app on OSX to push any changes I make to, for example, my local CSS or HTML files to the remote Github repository. That is as far as my basic understanding of Git takes me really.

Whenever existing content is edited or a new page/entry is published through the CMS's Control Panel, a file is updated or created inside the *_content* folder on the server where the site is hosted.

What I want is for Github to listen to and keep track of any changes made on the server, particularly that *_content* folder.

One of my attempts was to just upload the *.git* folder in my local files to my server and change the *Primary remote repository* path, but that didn't work.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Really the only way to run Git (the version control system, not GitHub the web application/network) is via SSH.

Here's a good article: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-on-Linux

And if you get that up and running, here's a good way to set up deployments: http://blog.ekynoxe.com/2011/10/22/automated-deployment-on-remote-server-with-git/

Comment: Wow, support beyond the Statamic support site - impressive! Seems like I won't get around going deep into the jungle of SSH and the command line... Thank you for the links :)